# Framework for runtime test definitions

Tags: unit-testing, parallel-processing, .net-6.0, xunit

I have a test environment where the test definitions are not known before runtime (test scripts loaded from a source a text.)

I have been working to build a test application (in dotnet) which loads these definitions and execute them as xUnit test in parallel.

This is difficult because xUnit parallelisation is defined via the class attribute `Collection` which cannot accept runtime parameters to name the collections uniquely.

Is there a method to force parallel execution in xUnit or am I looking at this problem the wrong way?

My current solution is to provide an abstract base class which implements the core test functionality and use a powershell script to generate a test class per downloaded test definition, prior to build and execution.